# Default select option for select list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

Here is the code to be checked:

```
f.select :engine_type_id, options_for_select(association_select_items(EngineType), selected: f.object.engine_type.id)
```

This code works good, but if f.object.engine_type is nil (for example, when object is being created) I got the error "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass". How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a new record or doesn't have an engine type you then can't do .id hence the error.  But assuming it's a belongs_to association it will have an engine_type_id column.

So make it

```
selected: f.object.engine_type_id
```

or if using form_for and it's for a @car object you can do

```
selected: @car.engine_type_id
```

Answer (score -1):

this isn't valid ruby:

```
f.select :engine_type_id, options_for_select(association_select_items(EngineType), selected: f.object.engine_type.id)
```

this part - `selected: f.object.engine_type.id` is javascript syntax for a key-value pair.  The ruby equivalent syntax is

```
:selected => f.object.engine_type.id
```

The key can be any object, but it's generally better to use symbols as keys for efficiency reasons (as well as convention).  (`:selected` is a symbol)

so the whole thing would be

```
f.select :engine_type_id, options_for_select(association_select_items(EngineType), :selected => f.object.engine_type.id)
```

The next problem, i think (it may be different in your version of rails) is that the options_for_select helper expects the default value to just be passed straight through as an argument after the array of options, ie

```
f.select :engine_type_id, options_for_select(association_select_items(EngineType), f.object.engine_type.id)
```

Like i say i'm not sure about this last part.  That's how it works in my version of rails anyway.

Comment: The latest versions of ruby will allow you to do selected: value

Comment: You can do java/ecmascript object notation in ruby now?  no wai.  My bad.

Comment: It's not exactly JSON. It's just a shorthand when a hash's key is a symbol. i.e., `{:symbol => "Value"}` can be written `{symbol: "Value"}`. But I don't think you can take anything arbitrary like `{1 => 2, 3 => 4}` and turn it into `{1: 2, 3: 4}`

Comment: Which TBH is a shame. As much as I like Ruby I miss a lot of Python syntax.